# How do I call a function from another React.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to call a function to show a modal dialog from another file.  The Modal dialog works.  I have `MyModal` rendering a button that I can click and it shows the modal dialog.  Very nice.  My problem is when I try to show that modal from other files.

**MyModal.jsx**

```
export default class MultiviewDialog extends React.Component {
    //some stuff here
    showModal() { ... }
}
```

**SomeOtherFile.jsx**

```
import MyModal from './MyModal.jsx';

showTheModal() {
    MyModal.showModal();
}

render() {
    //render something
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
SomeOtherFile.jsx:<LINE> Uncaught TypeError:_MyModal2.default.showModal is not a function(…)
```

What's with the "2" that it added in there?  How do I call the showModal function?

Comment: *"What's with the "2" that it added in there?"* That has to do with how Babel transforms module imports. *"How do I call the showModal function?"* How do you expect this function to work? Why is a method of a component **instance**? If you want a static method you have to define it with `static`. This has more to do with the basics of JavaScript classes than with React. But while we could tell you how to call that method, it's very likely not a solution to the overall problem. Again, what's the purpose of this method?

Comment: @FelixKling the modal is got from react-bootstrap (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modal-custom-sizing).  The showModal method sets a state, effectively revealing the modal dialog.  `this.setState({show: true});`  I've tried making `showModal` static but then get errors complaining that `this.setState` is not a function.

Comment: It might not be a good practice. It's better to fire an action to control the modal to show/hide.

Comment: You should render the modal like any other component and pass the visibility state as prop. No need for any methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `refs` to call the function inside a component class imported in someotherfile

```
import MyModal from './MyModal.jsx';

showTheModal = () => {
    this._child.showModal();   // this will call MyModal showmodal function
}

render() {
    //render something
    return (
      <MyModal ref={(child) => {this._child = child}}
   )
}
```